# Dynamic manipulation of TMX maps in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, tmx

Is it possible to dynamically manipulate loaded TMX map in AndEngine? For example, add objects on tile map, drag objects or resize a map?

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

You may only get parameters of TiledMap and TMXTile. You won't be able to set parameters and save them in your .tmx file(android doesn't let you modify /res and /assets files).

You may only modify your tmx layers, for example: set scale, set alpha, etc.

Comment: Yes, we can't modify assets files. Can I add objects or change tile map without saving changes in the tmx file?